# StackPanel in Web UI

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

StackPanel is a control in WPF, but I would like use it for web UI. Please provide me how can I do? And Are there any telerik control the same with it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't the same control.

Closest ones I am aware of:

- RadPanelBar: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx
- RadPageLayout which helps in creating responsive pages by providing some built-in grid layouts and configurations similar to bootstrap: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/pagelayout/overview.
- write some CSS to `float` your containers